# Do Chaos's move-specific damage buffs apply to Ares's doom damage?

Tags: hades

Let's say I get a Curse of Pain boon from Ares that makes my Special inflict Doom damage. If I get a boom from Chaos that increases my Special damage, does that damage buff apply to both the base special damage and the Doom damage?

Answer (score 1):

No. Doom is a status curse that in this case is being applied by your special, but its effects are unrelated to any buffs (from Chaos or Olympians) that you may have on your special. This is true for all status curses - for example, if you apply Hangover with your attack, the Hangover damage is not impacted by attack-related boons.

The only way to increase your Doom damage is by upgrading it with poms, getting other boons like Impending Doom, or by using abilities that provide global damage increases to all sources of damage (like Blood Frenzy).